# How to get RoundCube work with dovecot and postfix?

Tags: postfix, dovecot, roundcube

I just installed RoundCube, but I'm having difficulties configuring it. I've dovecot, postfix with MySQL installed and it's all running nice and dandy, but I would like to attach a web-mail to it.

When I visit the RoundCube webmail, I get this:

```
DATABASE ERROR: CONNECTION FAILED!

Unable to connect to the database!
Please contact your server-administrator.
```

It's most likely because I've this code in /etc/roundcube/debian-db.php, but I know for sure that I don't have such database with such user created:

```
$dbuser='roundcube';
$dbpass='3e5r6tgulhk4et';
$basepath='';
$dbname='roundcube';
$dbserver='';
$dbport='';
$dbtype='mysql';
```

What I would like RoundCube to do is to use the existing user mailbox information any everything as it's used with dovecot and postfix. What should I do in RoundCube to make that work?
I'm on Linux Debian Lenny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about reading the [documentation](http://trac.roundcube.net/wiki/Howto_Install)? Also, the fact that there is a database configuration file is a good hint that you need to create a database if the debian package didn't create one.

Comment: I already read it, but why to create a database when I've a postfix database with the user mailboxes and stuff already? What will this RoundCube database have? How to link it with it?

Comment: Roundcube needs it to store (per user) preferences that cannot be stored via IMAP. If you don't want a MySQL server for this, you can also use SQLite.

Comment: Thank you, that and installing correct roundcube mysql package did the trick.